# How Avoid re-initializing Activity That Takes a long time to initilize

Tags: android

I have an app with two screens, and buttons that switch between them. One screen is mainly a listView, but the other has a game engine in it (AndEngine) and it can take a while for the game engine to init the first time the activity is created. 
So switching between them can cause big delays when going to a new game Engine. However, if I just use the back button, the previous game engine loads much faster. 
Is there a way I can specify to crete only one game engine and always bring up that instance of the activity? Right now I am using startIntent() to swap screens. Is there some other way?
A way that allows me to just have a single instance of each activity and swap between them?

Comment: Is the engine an object? If yes, save it and restore it instead of initializing.

Comment: The Engine is a View. It extends Activity.

Comment: @Plastic: "However, if I just use the back button..." Calling `finish()` in your list view activity will effectively do the same as pressing the BACK button.

Comment: @MisterSquonk won't finish() do exactly what I dont want? that is - won't it tell android to kill the activity and garbage collect it? What I want is a way to switch between activities without having startIntent() create a new instance of the activity.

Comment: @Plastic: Your wording suggested that using the BACK button when in your 'list view' activity allows you to return to the 'game engine' activity more quickly. The wording of your question also suggests that if you go from your 'game engine' activity to your 'list view' activity and then want to return, you're using an Intent to start a new instance of the 'game engine' activity. Using `finish()`, however, would be the same as using the BACK button when you're in the 'list view' activity and will simply end the 'list view' activity and return you to the 'game engine' without creating a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android provides a simple way to switch between activities using a TabHost. You can also use it to switch between Fragments as explained under [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html). Alternatively, you can add a FrameLayout to your activity, programmatically instantiate the fragments and attach/show/hide them when needed.

Your res/layout/main.xml would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/mainframe">
</FrameLayout>
```

And assuming the v4 support library is used, your activity would look like this:

```
public MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private Fragment mListFrag;
    private Fragment mGameFrag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mListFrag = new MyListFragment();
        mGameFrag = new MyGameFragment();

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(
                R.id.mainframe,
                mListFrag,
                MyListFragment.class.getName())
            .add(
                R.id.mainframe,
                mGameFrag,
                MyGameFragment.class.getName())
            .detach(mGameFrag)
            .commit();

        fm.executePendingTransactions();
    }

    public void showList() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .hide(mGameFrag)
            .show(mListFrag)
            .commit();
    }

    public void showGame() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (mGameFrag.isDetached()) {
            ft.attach(mGameFrag);
        }
        ft.hide(mListFrag).show(mGameFrag).commit();
    }
}
```

Observe that MyGameFragment.onCreateView isn't called until it is first attached. After that, hiding and showing the fragments allows the user to switch without delay.

Edit: I realise now you wanted 2 activities with their own button. I've updated the code to reflect this. From the OnClickListeners simply call the relevant activity functions like so:

`((MyActivity) MyListFragment.this.getActivity()).showGame();`

Comment: I also found one other solution too: using android:launchMode="singleInstance" in the manifest.xml also caused the screen to function like a singleton. only one instance of the activity was ever created. But the tabs actually keep them both open and work the fastest. So I accepted that answer.

Comment: singleInstance does funny things, try launching your app and background it with the home button. Do that a couple of times and then try pressing the back button to return where you came from.