# Android - Change fragment layout in runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I would like to implement a Single-Activity Multi-Fragments design in my app. I plan to have several "screens" (layouts of Fragment) that I'll switch between (possibly adding to back-stack) in code.

To my understanding the layout of the fragments in each screen is set using Layout objects (e.g. FrameLayout), which act as placeholders for the fragments (sharing the same ID). Since different screens have different Fragment arrangements (one could be FrameLayout, and another LinearLayout, etc.) I was wondering: How do I switch between layouts of fragments in runtime?

I understand adding / replacing Fragments (via FragmentManager), but I'd like to completely add a new layout that contains them, within a live activity. Kind of like having transactions for "setContentView"...

How do I do this?
Thanks! Danny.

Comment: I posted single-activity multi-fragments code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797389/how-avoid-re-initializing-activity-that-takes-a-long-time-to-initilize/7799391#7799391

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, I think switching between fragments in the same layout like your example shows (`R.id.mainframe`), doesn't solve my problem, which is how to switch between layouts of fragments. Specially if the layouts are created in code (after onContentView is called), like my case.

Comment: Oh I see, so you want to re-parent existing fragments without re-instantiating them? That's interesting.

Comment: Sorry if my explanation is poor. :) I think my case is more simple. I want to create new fragments inside new layouts (no reparenting here). To my understanding, the FragmentManager cannot define new layouts, only connect fragments to existing place holders in the Activity layout. Since I want to create new Layouts, I have a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly possible, the only thing you need to do is to generate your own IDs. The IDs may be anything but they must not conflict with the aapt IDs (the ones in R) and must not be negative.

The following example demonstrates this with a set of fixed IDs:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final int ID_TABLE = 0xA;
    private final int ID_ROW1 = 0xB;
    private final int ID_ROW2 = 0xC;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
        TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);
        tl.setId(ID_TABLE);
        TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
        tr1.setId(ID_ROW1);
        TableRow tr2 = new TableRow(this);
        tr2.setId(ID_ROW2);
        tl.addView(tr1);
        tl.addView(tr2);
        ll.addView(tl);

        MyFragment frag1 = new MyFragment();
        MyFragment frag2 = new MyFragment();
        MyFragment frag3 = new MyFragment();
        MyFragment frag4 = new MyFragment();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(ID_ROW1, frag1, "cell1_1")
            .add(ID_ROW1, frag2, "cell1_2")
            .add(ID_ROW2, frag3, "cell2_1")
            .add(ID_ROW2, frag4, "cell2_2")
            .commit();
        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

In order to switch to a different layout, you can remove the fragments and add them elsewhere.
Let me know how it goes.

EDIT: to clarify, Views and ViewGroups don't need to be instantiated once and then kept for the lifetime of the Activity. Just make sure any fragments are either removed or detached before removing their associated view. Also, if you create and remove views outside of onCreate you should make sure it can be restored by using onSaveInstanceState and repeating the process in onCreate. Read the [diagram here](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and the paragraph about [configuration changes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges).

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Since I'm an Android newbie, I want to make sure I understood you correctly - is it okay to add / remove views and layouts from the main view of my activity pretty much anywhere in my code, and not just in the onCreate (I don't think I've seen examples for this), and then create and add fragments to them on the fly? It's a bit more than just "removing the fragments and adding them elsewhere", because I create a new layout for them.

Comment: The goal is eventually to separate this Fragment logic to different "screen" classes, and have each class know about its own layout IDs, and put its own fragments in them. Then I can navigate from one "screen" to another via fragment transactions. e.g. hide all fragments of previous screen and show the new fragments instead. I must admit, this technique seems a bit strange, as it will flood my activity with empty layouts with invisible fragments... It seems like my goal is reasonable but I haven't found the correct design for it.

Comment: Well that's an interesting train of thought, but isn't this exactly what activities and their startActivity(Intent) method were made for? You get back button functionality for free, too.

Comment: My problem with activities is that their whole existence is too "managed" by the framework. I understand the need when you want to expose your activities to the world, but not when they're inside your app... Anyway, I need my "screen" classes to generate their own view hierarchy on the fly, so I can't have an activity class for each screen. Instead, I need to create a screen instance, generate it's views and show/hide them by instance, and not by class. I'm also very likely to want to reuse my "screen" in a different layouts (tablets, etc.), where Fragments are ideal.

Comment: correction: I actually do see why you might want the framework to have the ability to kill and revive your activities for memory management. I just don't like the way they force it.

Comment: If you're that worried, you can use [android:launchMode="singleInstance"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) and keep the process as-is when it's moved to the background. Please make sure the back stack still works as intended, though.

Comment: The resource manager already covers using different layouts for different devices. [Please read this.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) You can have layout-large-land, layout-large-port, layout-long-port-mdpi, layout-small-port-tvdpi, etc. etc. I'm working on an application which has different layouts based on screen size, portrait/landscape and api level (e.g. layout-xlarge-land-v11). Only very little code deals with the different configurations.

Comment: Great! There is a whole lot of useful information here regarding my problem, so obviously your answer is accepted. It's also likely to be useful for others in their first steps of fragment development. I may have oversimplified my problem for the sake of making it a coherent question, so if I haven't exhausted your powers maybe it's worth moving to a chat? In any case, thank you very much!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4486/discussion-between-user999717-and-dannya)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.loadFragment(AlarmExample.newInstance())
this.loadFragment(XmlParsingFragment.newInstance())

private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
        .commit()
}
```

In this way, you can set any fragment, based upon your requirement.