# How to change layout of a fragment dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to change my layout of a Fragment on run time. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7865438/601868 - the same question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This I have done by again inflating the view with new layout using parent view.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContext = (RulesNativeActivity)this.getActivity();
        View v;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newFragment, container, false);
        return v;
    }
```